# get type of properties in C# reflection

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, c#-5.0

```
public class A
{
    public int i;
    public string s;
}

public class B
{
    public int bi;
    public A A;
}
```

Here I get the properties of `class B` which in turn returns both the properties available.
However I need to differentiate the normal class properties to the complex properties.
I need to handle the property `A` of `class B` differently. Can somebody advise how I can write code to decide that this property is of type of another class?

I just gave an example of `Class A` as child in `Class B` here. In real-time, there can be many children.

Comment: You might want to check your terminology here: neither `class A` nor `class B` have any properties in your example - they have fields.

Comment: @Chris, yes u r right. I meant properties only, by mistake typed variables :)

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to assume that by "normal class properties" and "complex properties" you mean value and reference types, as that's what your example seems to imply.

If this is the case, you can use `Type.IsValueType` to check whether the type of each field or property is a value type. If it *isn't* a value type, that means it is a reference to another class, and you can act accordingly.

Comment: System.String is not value type.In your answer case it will be treated as non value type goes into complex type flow, which is not what I needed